# ASP.NET TextBox Value are not being kept after PostBack - Session value OK

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, postback

I've got a simple ASP.NET GridView that is databound to a view on our database.

When a row is selected, the Request is added to the Session variables and to the Request ID TextBox. The TextBox's TextChanged event and the PostBack event both verify this as I step through the process, but the values are not displayed on the website afterwards.

The code is posted on .NET Pad here: http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/TJp2pldPkk6poP3cVzRlHQ

Note: I have also tried commenting out all of the code in the Page_Load for the PostBack event, but this did not solve my problem.

What could make this work?

Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<script runat="server">

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (IsPostBack) {
      //int nDDL = GetInteger(Session[ddlSelector.ID]);
      //if (nDDL == ddlSelector.SelectedIndex) {
      //  int reqID = GetInteger(Session[txtRequestID.ID]);
      //  if ((0 < reqID) && (reqID.ToString() != txtRequestID.Text)) {
      //    string strEmp = IsNumeric(Session[txtEmployee.ID]) ? GetText(Session[txtEmployee.ID]) : null;
      //    txtRequestID.Text = reqID.ToString();
      //    txtEmployee.Text = strEmp;
      //    if (nDDL != ddlChangeTo.SelectedIndex) {
      //      ddlChangeTo.SelectedIndex = nDDL;
      //    }
      //  }
      //}
    } else {
      Session[ddlSelector.ID] = null;
      Session[txtRequestID.ID] = null;
      Session[txtEmployee.ID] = null;
      txtRequestID.Text = null;
      txtEmployee.Text = null;
      txtMTF.Text = null;
      btnOK.Visible = (0 < GetInteger(txtRequestID.Text));
    }
  }

  private void ErrorMessage(string message) {
    Response.Write(string.Format("<font color=\"Red\"><b>{0}</b></font>", message));
  }

  protected void GridViewRow_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    if (row != null) {
      var reqIdCell = row.Cells[1];
      if (reqIdCell != null) {
        int reqID = GetInteger(reqIdCell.Text);
        if (0 < reqID) {
          Session[ddlSelector.ID] = ddlSelector.SelectedIndex;
          Session[txtRequestID.ID] = reqID;
          txtRequestID.Text = reqID.ToString();
          txtEmployee.Text = null;
          btnOK.Visible = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int reqID = GetInteger(Session[txtRequestID.ID]);
    if (0 < reqID) {
      ErrorMessage("Success!");
    } else {
      ErrorMessage("Unrecognised Request ID.");
      txtRequestID.Focus();
    }
  }

  protected void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (sender is TextBox) {
      TextBox tbx = (TextBox)sender;
      if (tbx.ID == txtRequestID.ID) {
        int reqID = GetInteger(txtRequestID.Text.Trim());
        int reqI2 = GetInteger(Session[txtRequestID.ID]);
        if (0 < reqID) {
          Session[txtRequestID.ID] = reqID;
        } else {
          txtRequestID.Text = null;
        }
        if (0 < reqI2) {
          txtRequestID.Text = reqI2.ToString();
        }
      } else if (tbx.ID == txtEmployee.ID) {
        string empNum = txtEmployee.Text.Trim();
        if (IsNumeric(empNum)) {
          Session[txtEmployee.ID] = empNum;
        } else {
          txtEmployee.Text = null;
        }
      }
    } else if (sender is DropDownList) {
      DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
      if (ddl.ID == ddlSelector.ID) {
        Session[ddlSelector.ID] = ddlSelector.SelectedIndex;
        Session[txtRequestID.ID] = null;
        Session[txtEmployee.ID] = null;
      }
    }
  }

  protected void Tick_Tock(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GridView1.DataBind();
  }

  private static int GetInteger(object value) {
    int result = -1;
    if (HasValue(value)) {
      try {
        result = (int)value;
      } catch {
        result = -1;
      }
    }
    if (result == -1) {
      result = 0; // errors could occur if I try indexing things with negative numbers
      string text = GetText(value);
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) {
        int.TryParse(text.Trim(), out result);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  private static string GetText(object value) {
    if (HasValue(value)) {
      return value.ToString().Trim();
    }
    return null;
  }

  private static bool HasValue(object item) {
    if ((item != null) && (item != DBNull.Value)) {
      return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString().Trim());
    }
    return false;
  }

  private static bool IsNumeric(object input) {
    if (input == null) return false;
    string text = input.ToString();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Trim())) {
      foreach (char c in text.ToCharArray()) {
        if (char.IsLetter(c)) return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

</script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="productionDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CPWEB_PRODUCTION %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [RequestID], [Employee], [DateStamp], [Line], [PartNo], [Workorder], [Qty], [MTF], [Status] FROM [vwRequestsEx] WHERE ([Status] = @Status)"><SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSelector" Name="Status" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters></asp:SqlDataSource>
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />
      <table style="width: 90%">
        <tr>
          <td>Display:<br /><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelector" runat="server" DataSourceID="productionStatus2" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Description" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="productionStatus2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CPWEB_PRODUCTION %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Description] FROM [Status]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
          </td>
          <td>RequestID:<br /><asp:TextBox ID="txtRequestID" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" /></td>
          <td>Employee:<br /><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployee" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" /></td>
          <td>MTF:<br /><asp:TextBox ID="txtMTF" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" /></td>
          <td style="width: 110px;">Change To:<br /><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChangeTo" runat="server" DataSourceID="productionStatus3" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Description"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="productionStatus3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CPWEB_PRODUCTION %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Description] FROM [Status] WHERE ([Description] &lt;&gt; @Description)"><SelectParameters>
              <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSelector" Name="Description" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters></asp:SqlDataSource>
          </td>
          <td><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" Width="75px" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="nowrap" colspan="6">
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Tick_Tock" runat="server" Interval="30000"></asp:Timer>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
              <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" /></Triggers>
              <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" CellPadding="1" DataSourceID="productionDataSource2" EmptyDataText="No Records to Display" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewRow_Selected" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" RowHeaderColumn="RequestID" Width="95%">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestID" HeaderText="RequestID" SortExpression="RequestID" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee" HeaderText="Employee" SortExpression="Employee" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="DateStamp" HeaderText="DateStamp" SortExpression="DateStamp" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Line" HeaderText="Line" SortExpression="Line" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="PartNo" HeaderText="PartNo" SortExpression="PartNo" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Workorder" HeaderText="Workorder" SortExpression="Workorder" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" HeaderText="Qty" SortExpression="Qty" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="MTF" HeaderText="MTF" SortExpression="MTF" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2"></SortedAscendingCellStyle><SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle><SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8"></SortedDescendingCellStyle><SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle></asp:GridView></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **NOTE:** The larger project for this does use code behind. I only created this standalone project in an effort to locate the problem. I wished I could link to the database for others to test.

Comment: Have you tried tracing through the code in debug mode?

Comment: @SystemDown - I mentioned in the original post that I have verified that my values are set *as I step through the process, but the values are not displayed on the website afterwards.* That's how I trace in debug mode. What else are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting the actual portion you have problem with would get you better answer instead of this.

You don't need all the else portion, just do this

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         //code to execute here only when an action is taken by the user
         //and not affected by PostBack
    }

    //these codes should be affected by PostBack
 }
```

Hope it helps!

**Update**

I believe your UpdatePanel is what is causing the problem. Removing the UpdatePanel, things look OK.

The reason controls at the top were not being updated is because they are not in the UpdatePanel, any changes you make from codebehind by controls in the UpdatePanel (e.g. PostBack by the "Select" link) will never get to them.

One solution is to also include those controls at the top, e.g. RequestID textbox in the UpdatePanel.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But, my code has that, doesn't it? It shows above `if (Postback) { /* commented out */ } else { /* this is the only section of code I am executing, but the problem still occurs */ }` Am I missing something?

Comment: SO never informed me of the update. I just saw it, and that might solve my problem. Thanks!